# load data using parse server in one array

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to load data using parse server but I do not know what kind of array I use. I want build app like snapchat - all post that user have should be in one array. I hope you understand what I'm saying.

This is the example :

```
userArr = [
        ["name" : "Keila Maney", "pro-image" : "pro-img-3",
             "items": [["content" : "image", "item" : "img-3"], ["content" : "video", "item" : "output"], ["content" : "video", "item" : "output2"]]],

        ["name" : "Gilberto", "pro-image" : "pro-img-1",
             "items": [["content" : "video", "item" : "output3"], ["content" : "image", "item" : "img-4"], ["content" : "image", "item" : "img-5"], ["content" : "video", "item" : "output"]]],
        ["name" : "Jonathan", "pro-image" : "pro-img-2",

             "items": [["content" : "image", "item" : "img-1"], ["content" : "video", "item" : "output2"]]],

        ["name" : "Delmer", "pro-image" : "pro-img-4",
             "items": [["content" : "image", "item" : "img-2"], ["content" : "video", "item" : "output"], ["content" : "image", "item" : "img-3"]]],

        ["name" : "Carolyne", "pro-image" : "pro-img-3",
             "items": [["content" : "video", "item" : "output"], ["content" : "image", "item" : "img-4"], ["content" : "video", "item" : "output3"], ["content" : "image", "item" : "img-3"]]],

        ["name" : "Sabine", "pro-image" : "pro-img-5",
             "items": [["content" : "video", "item" : "output2"], ["content" : "image", "item" : "img-5"], ["content" : "video", "item" : "output3"]]],
    ]
}
```

Comment: The `Items` collection should ideally be separate from the `User` collection

Answer (score 2):

Hi the first Step will be to get the friend list then the post of all the friends.

you have to request the Friend list of the current user by using a PFQuery Object and the method findObjectsInBackground. In the answer block you will receive an Array of PFUsers. Just run a for loop and fetch the Post of all friends. That is it.

```
func getProfileTimeLine(completion:@escaping(_ posts: [Post]?, _ error:Error?)->Void){

 let query = PFQuery(className: Post.className)

 query.order(byDescending:"updatedAt")
    query.whereKey("author", equalTo: Friend)
    query.includeKey("author")
    query.limit = 20

    // fetch data asynchronously
    query.findObjectsInBackground { (friendPosts, error) in
        if error == nil{
            if let postsObjects = friendPosts{
                completion(postsObjects, error)
            }
        }else{
            completion(nil, error)
        }
    }
}
```